# CAS Can't give closed form value for a definite integral involving $E$ (complete elliptic integral pf the 2nd kind)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve this integral;
$$
\int^a_{-a}\frac{E[\frac{-(4b_1 b_2)}{((x+z)^2+(b_1-b_2)^2 )}]}{((x+z)^2+(b_1+b_2)^2)\sqrt{((x+z)^2+(b_1-b_2)^2 )}}dx
$$
E is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind. Since it is very complicated, I tried to use CAS(Computer Algebra System) like Mathematica and Maple. However, neither Mathematica nor Maple could solve my problem. I am searching for a specialized CAS for integrals which can solve this integral. Does anyone know any CAS that is specialized on integrals?

P.S:If anyone can solve the integral for me, that would be amazing. Please tell me if you want to solve the integral so I can give you the background of the variables.

Comment: I would also be amazed if this can be solved analytically .. Because remember you can always try to solve this numerically ;)

Comment: @Chinny84 I see but I have to find the solution analytically. Thus I am pretty desperate right now.

Comment: @Chinny84 I gave up and tried to solve it numerically but since I can't give x a value CAS again couldn't solve the elliptic integral.What can I do?

Answer (score 5):

We can define the complete elliptic integral of the second kind as a function of the parameter $m\le1$ through the standard integral representation as

$$E{\left[m\right]}:=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{1-mx^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}.$$

Let $a,b,c,z\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\land b>c$.

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(a,b,c,z\right)}
&=\int_{-a}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{E{\left[-\frac{4bc}{\left(x+z\right)^2+\left(b-c\right)^2}\right]}}{\left[\left(x+z\right)^2+\left(b+c\right)^2\right]\sqrt{\left(x+z\right)^2+\left(b-c\right)^2}}\\
&=\int_{z-a}^{z+a}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{E{\left[-\frac{4bc}{y^2+\left(b-c\right)^2}\right]}}{\left[y^2+\left(b+c\right)^2\right]\sqrt{y^2+\left(b-c\right)^2}};~~~\small{\left[x+z=y\right]}\\
&=\int_{z-a}^{z+a}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{\left[y^2+\left(b+c\right)^2\right]\sqrt{y^2+\left(b-c\right)^2}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{1-\left[-\frac{4bc}{y^2+\left(b-c\right)^2}\right]x^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{z-a}^{z+a}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{\left[y^2+\left(b+c\right)^2\right]\sqrt{y^2+\left(b-c\right)^2}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{\frac{y^2+\left(b-c\right)^2+4bcx^{2}}{y^2+\left(b-c\right)^2}}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{z-a}^{z+a}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{y^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}{\left[y^{2}+\left(b+c\right)^{2}\right]\left[y^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}\right]\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{z-a}^{z+a}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{y^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}{\left[y^{2}+\left(b+c\right)^{2}\right]\left[y^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}\right]\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\int_{z-a}^{z+a}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\sqrt{y^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}{\left[y^{2}+\left(b+c\right)^{2}\right]\left[y^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\int_{z-a}^{z+a}\mathrm{d}y\,\\
&~~~~~\times\frac{y^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}{\left[y^{2}+\left(b+c\right)^{2}\right]\left[y^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}\right]\sqrt{y^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\int_{z-a}^{z+a}\mathrm{d}y\,\left[\frac{1-x^{2}}{y^{2}+\left(b+c\right)^{2}}+\frac{x^{2}}{y^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}}\right]\\
&~~~~~\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1-x^{2}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\int_{z-a}^{z+a}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{\left[y^{2}+\left(b+c\right)^{2}\right]\sqrt{y^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\int_{z-a}^{z+a}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{\left[y^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}\right]\sqrt{y^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1-x^{2}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\int_{z-a}^{z+a}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{d}{dy}\left[\frac{\operatorname{artanh}{\left(\frac{y\sqrt{4bc\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}{\left(b+c\right)\sqrt{y^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\right)}}{\left(b+c\right)\sqrt{4bc\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\int_{z-a}^{z+a}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{d}{dy}\left[\frac{\arctan{\left(\frac{y\sqrt{4bcx^{2}}}{\left(b-c\right)\sqrt{y^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\right)}}{\left(b-c\right)\sqrt{4bcx^{2}}}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1-x^{2}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\cdot\frac{\operatorname{artanh}{\left(\frac{\left(z+a\right)\sqrt{4bc\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}{\left(b+c\right)\sqrt{\left(z+a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\right)}-\operatorname{artanh}{\left(\frac{\left(z-a\right)\sqrt{4bc\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}{\left(b+c\right)\sqrt{\left(z-a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\right)}}{\left(b+c\right)\sqrt{4bc\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\cdot\frac{\arctan{\left(\frac{\left(z+a\right)\sqrt{4bcx^{2}}}{\left(b-c\right)\sqrt{\left(z+a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\right)}-\arctan{\left(\frac{\left(z-a\right)\sqrt{4bcx^{2}}}{\left(b-c\right)\sqrt{\left(z-a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\right)}}{\left(b-c\right)\sqrt{4bcx^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\operatorname{artanh}{\left(\frac{2\left(z+a\right)\sqrt{bc}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{\left(b+c\right)\sqrt{\left(z+a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\right)}-\operatorname{artanh}{\left(\frac{2\left(z-a\right)\sqrt{bc}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{\left(b+c\right)\sqrt{\left(z-a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\right)}}{2\left(b+c\right)\sqrt{bc}}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\cdot\frac{\arctan{\left(\frac{2\left(z+a\right)x\sqrt{bc}}{\left(b-c\right)\sqrt{\left(z+a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\right)}-\arctan{\left(\frac{2\left(z-a\right)x\sqrt{bc}}{\left(b-c\right)\sqrt{\left(z-a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\right)}}{2\left(b-c\right)\sqrt{bc}},\\
\end{align}$$

and then, integrating by parts we find

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(a,b,c,z\right)}
&=-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,x\bigg{[}-\frac{\left(z+a\right)x}{\left[\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}\right]\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\sqrt{\left(z+a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\left(z-a\right)x}{\left[\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}\right]\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\sqrt{\left(z-a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\bigg{]}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[-\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\right]\bigg{[}\frac{\left(z+a\right)}{\left[\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}\right]\sqrt{\left(z+a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{\left(z-a\right)}{\left[\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}\right]\sqrt{\left(z-a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\bigg{]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\bigg{[}\frac{\left(z+a\right)x^{2}}{\left[\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}\right]\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\sqrt{\left(z+a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{\left(z-a\right)x^{2}}{\left[\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}\right]\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\sqrt{\left(z-a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\bigg{]}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\bigg{[}\frac{\left(z+a\right)\left(1-x^{2}\right)}{\left[\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}\right]\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\sqrt{\left(z+a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{\left(z-a\right)\left(1-x^{2}\right)}{\left[\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}\right]\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\sqrt{\left(z-a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\bigg{]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(z+a\right)}{\left[\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}\right]\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\sqrt{\left(z+a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(z-a\right)}{\left[\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}\right]\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\sqrt{\left(z-a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bcx^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{\left(z+a\right)}{\left[\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bc\cos^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\right]\sqrt{\left(z+a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bc\cos^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}}}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{\left(z-a\right)}{\left[\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bc\cos^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\right]\sqrt{\left(z-a\right)^{2}+\left(b-c\right)^{2}+4bc\cos^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}}};~~~\small{\left[x=\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{\left(z+a\right)}{\left[\left(b+c\right)^{2}-4bc\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\right]\sqrt{\left(z+a\right)^{2}+\left(b+c\right)^{2}-4bc\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}}}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{\left(z-a\right)}{\left[\left(b+c\right)^{2}-4bc\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\right]\sqrt{\left(z-a\right)^{2}+\left(b+c\right)^{2}-4bc\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}}}\\
&=\frac{\left(z+a\right)}{\left(b+c\right)^{2}\sqrt{\left(z+a\right)^{2}+\left(b+c\right)^{2}}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{1}{\left[1-\frac{4bc}{\left(b+c\right)^{2}}\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\right]\sqrt{1-\frac{4bc}{\left(z+a\right)^{2}+\left(b+c\right)^{2}}\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}}}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{\left(z-a\right)}{\left(b+c\right)^{2}\sqrt{\left(z-a\right)^{2}+\left(b+c\right)^{2}}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{1}{\left[1-\frac{4bc}{\left(b+c\right)^{2}}\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\right]\sqrt{1-\frac{4bc}{\left(z-a\right)^{2}+\left(b+c\right)^{2}}\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}}}\\
&=\frac{\left(z+a\right)}{\left(b+c\right)^{2}\sqrt{\left(z+a\right)^{2}+\left(b+c\right)^{2}}}\Pi{\left(\frac{4bc}{\left(b+c\right)^{2}},\frac{2\sqrt{bc}}{\sqrt{\left(z+a\right)^{2}+\left(b+c\right)^{2}}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{\left(z-a\right)}{\left(b+c\right)^{2}\sqrt{\left(z-a\right)^{2}+\left(b+c\right)^{2}}}\Pi{\left(\frac{4bc}{\left(b+c\right)^{2}},\frac{2\sqrt{bc}}{\sqrt{\left(z-a\right)^{2}+\left(b+c\right)^{2}}}\right)}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

---